# Amadeus Cancel PNR XML returning empty response

Tags: web-services, amadeus

I have been trying to cancel reservation on Amadeus and each time I do that with a valid PNR, it returns an empty response. Below is the sample code

cancelPNR Request XML

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body>
            <wmPNRCancel xmlns="http://traveltalk.com/wsPNRCancel">
                <OTA_CancelRQ>
                  <POS>
    <Source PseudoCityCode="*******" ISOCurrency="NGN">
     <RequestorID Type="21" ID="********"/>
    </Source>
     <TPA_Extensions>
        <Provider>
           <Name>Amadeus</Name> 
           <System>Test</System> 
           <Userid>******</Userid> 
           <Password>**********</Password> 
        </Provider>
     </TPA_Extensions>
  </POS>
                  <UniqueID ID="******"/>
                </OTA_CancelRQ>
               </wmPNRCancel> 
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

cancelPNR response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<wmPNRCancelResponse xmlns="http://traveltalk.com/wsPNRCancel" />
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What could be wrong ? Please I need help

Comment: If you can share your raw request and response (i.e. not your wrapper, but the actual raw xml request that is sent to Amadeus) then that will help to see if there is anything to help with. Also, is this for a hotel booking?

Comment: Hi @Dave, this is for an itinerary reservation, the reservation has been done already, I am trying to cancel the reservation by running cancel PNR request and that is basically the raw request and the raw response XMLs

Comment: ,this would indicate to me that there was a communication problem somewhere within the Amadeus systems, or between Amadeus and the supplier if it is external content (i.e. car, hotel or non Amadeus hosted airline). Does the request have a property of RetransmissionIndicator? If it does, try sending the exact same request, but add RetransmissionIndicator and set it to true and you should certainly get something back as that would demand a response of some type from Amadeus. If it doesn't have that property, can you show us the schema?